How to use drag and drop gesture to CollectionView in MAUI
I am trying to implement drag-and-drop functionality for CollectionView in my .NET MAUI project.
When I try to drag the image, the program pauses due to an exception. How can I fix this?
The ItemDragged function displays the image path in debug console, but after that, the program pauses.
Here is code
Xaml code

                <!-- CollectionView to Display Additional Images -->
                <CollectionView Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="4" HorizontalItemSpacing="10" VerticalItemSpacing="10" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border StrokeThickness="0" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 12" HeightRequest="80" WidthRequest="80">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" Aspect="AspectFill">
                                    <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding BindingContext.ImageTappedCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding ImagePath}" />
                                         <DragGestureRecognizer
                                        CanDrag="True"
                                        DragStartingCommand="{Binding BindingContext.ItemDraggedCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}}"
                                        DragStartingCommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                                    <DropGestureRecognizer
                                        AllowDrop="True"
                                        DragLeaveCommand="{Binding BindingContext.ItemDragLeaveCommand,Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}}"
                                        DragLeaveCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        DragOverCommand="{Binding BindingContext.ItemDraggedOverCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}}"
                                        DragOverCommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                        DropCommand="{Binding BindingContext.ItemDroppedCommand, Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentPage}}}"
                                        DropCommandParameter="{Binding .}" />

                                    </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                </Image>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>

ViewModel code
public partial class PostJobStepOneViewModel : BaseViewModel { 
private readonly RoutingService routingService;
private readonly Repo repo; 
public ObservableCollection<Image> Images { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Image>(); 
public Command<Image> ItemDraggedCommand { get; } 
public Command<Image> ItemDragLeaveCommand { get; } 
public Command<Image> ItemDraggedOverCommand{ get; } 
public Command<Image> ItemDroppedCommand { get; } 
private Image _itemBeingDragged;
public PostJobStepOneViewModel(RoutingService routingService, Repo repo) 
{ 
    this.routingService = routingService; this.repo = repo; 
    ItemDraggedCommand = new Command<Image>(ItemDragged); 
    ItemDragLeaveCommand = new Command<Image>(ItemDragLeave); 
    ItemDraggedOverCommand = new Command<Image>(ItemDraggedOver); 
    ItemDroppedCommand = new Command<Image>(ItemDropped); 
}

public void ItemDragged(Image imagePath)
        {   
            imagePath.IsBeingDragged = true;
            _itemBeingDragged = imagePath;
             Debug.WriteLine($"ItemDragged: {imagePath?.ImagePath}");
        }
        
        public void ItemDragLeave(Image imagePath)
        {
             Debug.WriteLine($"ItemDragLeave: {imagePath?.ImagePath}");
            imagePath.IsBeingDraggedOver = false;
        }
        public void ItemDraggedOver(Image imagePath)
        {
              Debug.WriteLine($"ItemDraggedOver: {imagePath?.ImagePath}");
            if (imagePath == _itemBeingDragged)
            {
                imagePath.IsBeingDragged = false;
            }
            imagePath.IsBeingDraggedOver = imagePath != _itemBeingDragged;
        }
 
        public void ItemDropped(Image imagePath)
        {
            try
            {
                var itemToMove = _itemBeingDragged;
                var itemToInsertBefore = imagePath;
                if (itemToMove == null || itemToInsertBefore == null || itemToMove == itemToInsertBefore)
                    return;
                int insertAtIndex = Images.IndexOf(itemToInsertBefore);
                if (insertAtIndex >= 0 && insertAtIndex < Images.Count)
                {
                    Images.Remove(itemToMove);
                    Images.Insert(insertAtIndex, itemToMove);
                    itemToMove.IsBeingDragged = false;
                    itemToInsertBefore.IsBeingDraggedOver = false;
                }
                Debug.WriteLine($"ItemDropped: {imagePath?.ImagePath}");
                // Debug.WriteLine($"ItemDropped: [{itemToMove?.ImagePath}] => [{itemToInsertBefore?.ImagePath}], target index = [{insertAtIndex}]");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)


            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public partial class Image : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private string imagePath;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool isBeingDragged;
        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool isBeingDraggedOver;
    }
    
}




the program pauses due to an exception. Did you mean the application crash? In addition, did you test it on all the platforms?

It doesn’t crash; it just stops working and seems stuck.

What platform did you test on? I can't create a sample according to the code you provided. Could you please show the full code in the Page and ViewModel?

I tested on android. Yes Sure

code is too long how can i share ?

You can check this : How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Or you can just add the code about the viewmodel. I need the code about variable refered by the ItemDropped method.

Please edit your question and add the code. Don't post it in the comment.

@LiyunZhang-MSFT done

I created a new project and I delete some code such as TapCommand and RoutingService because you didn't provide them.
And then, I test it on both android and windows platform:

On the Windows:

There is no any problem. You can drag and drop the image with the pointer easily.

On the Android:

You can drag the Image when you long press on it. This is different from the windows.

When I try to drag the image, the program pauses due to an exception

This is because you drag it at once when you pressed on it. You can try to long press to drag it.
Edit:
The ViewModel code:
public partial class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    public ObservableCollection<Image> Images { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Image>();

    private Image _itemBeingDragged;

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Images.Add(new Image() { ImagePath = "dotnet_bot.png" });
        Images.Add(new Image() { ImagePath = "dotnet_bot.png" });
        Images.Add(new Image() { ImagePath = "dotnet_bot.png" });
        Images.Add(new Image() { ImagePath = "dotnet_bot.png" });
        Images.Add(new Image() { ImagePath = "dotnet_bot.png" });

    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void ItemDragged(Image imagePath)
    {
        imagePath.IsBeingDragged = true;
        _itemBeingDragged = imagePath;
        Debug.WriteLine($"ItemDragged: {imagePath?.ImagePath}");
    }
    [RelayCommand]
    public void ItemDragLeave(Image imagePath)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"ItemDragLeave: {imagePath?.ImagePath}");
        imagePath.IsBeingDraggedOver = false;
    }
    [RelayCommand]
    public void ItemDraggedOver(Image imagePath)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"ItemDraggedOver: {imagePath?.ImagePath}");
        if (imagePath == _itemBeingDragged)
        {
            imagePath.IsBeingDragged = false;
        }
        imagePath.IsBeingDraggedOver = imagePath != _itemBeingDragged;
    }
    [RelayCommand]
    public void ItemDropped(Image imagePath)
    {
        try
        {
            var itemToMove = _itemBeingDragged;
            var itemToInsertBefore = imagePath;
            if (itemToMove == null || itemToInsertBefore == null || itemToMove == itemToInsertBefore)
                return;
            int insertAtIndex = Images.IndexOf(itemToInsertBefore);
            if (insertAtIndex >= 0 && insertAtIndex < Images.Count)
            {
                Images.Remove(itemToMove);
                Images.Insert(insertAtIndex, itemToMove);
                itemToMove.IsBeingDragged = false;
                itemToInsertBefore.IsBeingDraggedOver = false;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine($"ItemDropped: {imagePath?.ImagePath}");
            // Debug.WriteLine($"ItemDropped: [{itemToMove?.ImagePath}] => [{itemToInsertBefore?.ImagePath}], target index = [{insertAtIndex}]");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
   
}

I used the ObservableObject and [RelayCommand] because you didn't provide the code about BaseViewModel.
And you can check the reslut image.

its not working

I have post the the code and result iamge. Please check it. @AminaTariq

Can you share the XAML code?

I just create a new Page and put the code you provided in the VerticalStackLayout. Did n't change anything. @AminaTariq
